# Tengo problemas para mandar una respuesta con express de unos datos obtenidos de MongoDB en Node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express

Hice un servidor con express en Node.js y quiero mandar como respuesta a una petición GET, datos que obtengo desde MongoDB.
El problema es que llegan como una promesa aunque la petición se haga mucho tiempo después de obtener los datos.
Agradecería mucho su ayuda, lo necesito mucho para un proyecto.
Adjunto mi código en Node.js.

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const dbname = xxxx
const coleccion = xxxx
const uri = xxxx

async function getData() {

    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    await client.connect()

    const cursor = await client.db(dbname)
        .collection(coleccion)
        .find({})

    const result = await cursor.toArray()

    return result

}

const datos = getData()


app.get('/mascotas', (req, res)=>{
    console.log(datos)
    res.send(datos)
})


puerto = 5500
app.listen(puerto, () => {
    console.log(`Puerto ${puerto}. Escuchando`)
});
```

Los datos en la consola me llegan como una Promesa asi:

```
[
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("63561b225893c3f07e0c635b"),
      animal: 'perro',
      nombre: 'hueso'
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("63561b625893c3f07e0c635c"),
      animal: 'gato',
      nombre: 'pelo'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tu función middleware que maneja la ruta no está trabajando correctamente con el código asíncrono.

```js
app.get('/mascotas', (req, res)=>{
    console.log(datos)
    res.send(datos)
});
```

Llamar a la función que obtiene los datos de esta forma no es conveniente, ya que se ejecutará 1 sola vez al iniciarse el programa y luego nunca más.

```js
const datos = getData()


app.get('/mascotas', (req, res)=>{
  ...
});
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución dependerá de cómo desees trabajar con el método asíncrono. Por ejemplo si deseas usar `async / await` en el middleware que maneja la ruta, podrías hacerlo así:

```js
app.get('/mascotas', async (req, res)=>{
  try {
    const datos = await getData();
    console.log(datos);
    return res.send(datos);
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.error(e.message);
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: 'Algo fue mal con la consulta!'
    });
  }
});
```

Cuando trabajamos con `async / await` debemos siempre usar `try ... catch` para poder capturar cualquier excepción o Promesa rechazada.

Si deseas usar `then()` y `catch()` podrías hacerlo de esta manera:

```js
app.get('/mascotas', (req, res)=>{
  getData()
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.error(e.message);
      res.status(500).json({
        message: 'Algo fue mal con la consulta!'
      });
    });
});
```

De esta forma, cada vez que alguien accede a la ruta `'/mascotas'` simepre obtendrá los datos al realizar la llamada a MongoDB.

Si bien esta sería una forma de solucionar el problema, tienes otro aún mayor, y es que cada vez que alguien accede a dicha ruta, estás abriendo una conexión nueva a la base de datos, y no la estás cerrando.

Aquí entras en escenarios de debate. Hay quienes opinan dejar la conexión abierta, es decir, que al iniciar tu aplicación se realice una conexión a MongoDB y se reutlice la misma en toda la aplicación o por el contrario, que por cada petición se realice una nueva conexión.

Todo esto va a depender de tu necesidad. Pero si deseas cerrar la conexión una vez se tiene la información solicitada basta con modificar la fucnión `getData` de la siguiente forma:

```js
async function getData() {
  const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
  await client.connect();  // <- se abre la conexión
  const cursor = await client.db(dbname)
    .collection(coleccion)
    .find({});
  const result = await cursor.toArray();
  await client.close();  // <- se cierra la conexión
  return result;
}
```

Por último, si bien hacerlo así es suficiente, lo recomendable es [**no cerrar la conexión**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495975/why-is-it-recommended-not-to-close-a-mongodb-connection-anywhere-in-node-js-code).

Si deseas usar la misma conexión a lo largo de toda la vida de tu aplicación, todo cambiaría de la siguiente forma:

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const dbname = xxxx;
const coleccion = xxxx;
const uri = xxxx;
const puerto = 5500;

const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
client.connect()
.then(() => {

  async function getData() {
    const cursor = await client.db(dbname)
      .collection(coleccion)
      .find({});
    const result = await cursor.toArray();
    return result;
  }
  
  app.get('/mascotas', async (req, res)=>{
    try {
      const datos = await getData();
      console.log(datos);
      return res.send(datos);
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.error(e.message);
      return res.status(500).json({
        message: 'Algo fue mal con la consulta!'
      });
    }
  });

  app.listen(puerto, () => {
    console.log(`Puerto ${puerto}. Escuchando`);
  });

})
.catch(e => {
  console.log('Error de conexión a la base de datos');
  console.error(e.message);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Como observas, el servidor de Express es levantado dentro de la función callback pasada a `then()`. Esta es una forma de hacerlo, existen otras. Pero la idea general es crear la conexión y reutilizarla siempre en la aplicación.

Si la conexión con MongoDB fallara, la aplicación tal vez no tendría sentido, por lo tanto el programa sale con un estado de error distinto de cero.

Además, y aunque parezca una nimiedad, todas las sentencias de mi código llevan `;` al final. Es algo de buenas prácticas.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, ha sido de mucha ayuda. Una pregunta sobre tu respuesta, cada petición el servidor tiene que ir a la base de datos por la información e imagino que esto puede ser lento. Hay alguna forma de traer los datos antes de la petición?

Comment: Claro, pero toma en cuenta que si insertas datos nuevos nunca los verás. Por lo tanto, lo de lentitud es relativo. Una petición entre tu servidor de aplicación y tu servidor de base de datos no debería ser muy lenta. Si el servidor está en el mismo entorno de red que la aplicación, sería casi inmediata. En todo caso, **todas** las aplicaciones funcionan de esa manera, por lo cual no le veo mucho inconveniente. A menos que la cantidad de datos solicitados sea una total locura, pero supongo que no es el caso. Saludos